# Intel NUC BEH2-i3 Internet RX drops/packet loss and device interrupt

Tags: networking, intel, ifconfig, intel-nuc

I recently switched from windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04LTS because i want to host a server (minecraft)
Now it appears i have packet loss as i see this on ifconfig and netdata (webmonitor).

I get the following error? by doing **ifconfig**

```
    RX packets 1400  bytes 247141 (247.1 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 55  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1546  bytes 1643883 (1.6 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 16 memory 0xb0a00000-b0a20000
```

How can i minimize the dropped packages or fix it?
And how to fix the device interrupt?
i Found some drops using the DropWatch, but i still dont know how to fix them... Or cant i fix them?

```
8 drops at netlink_broadcast_filtered+257 (0xffffffff8639f0e7)
3 drops at __netif_receive_skb_core+14e (0xffffffff8633411e)
2 drops at __udp4_lib_rcv+ae5 (0xffffffff863e9da5)
```

ethtool says

```
     rx_packets: 3547688
     tx_packets: 6997554
     rx_bytes: 256636051
     tx_bytes: 2044450064
     rx_broadcast: 13215
     tx_broadcast: 8
     rx_multicast: 8925
     tx_multicast: 134
     rx_errors: 0
     tx_errors: 0
     tx_dropped: 0
     multicast: 8925
     collisions: 0
     rx_length_errors: 0
     rx_over_errors: 0
     rx_crc_errors: 0
     rx_frame_errors: 0
     rx_no_buffer_count: 0
     rx_missed_errors: 0
     tx_aborted_errors: 0
     tx_carrier_errors: 0
     tx_fifo_errors: 0
     tx_heartbeat_errors: 0
     tx_window_errors: 0
     tx_abort_late_coll: 0
     tx_deferred_ok: 0
     tx_single_coll_ok: 0
     tx_multi_coll_ok: 0
     tx_timeout_count: 0
     tx_restart_queue: 0
     rx_long_length_errors: 0
     rx_short_length_errors: 0
     rx_align_errors: 0
     tx_tcp_seg_good: 4130
     tx_tcp_seg_failed: 0
     rx_flow_control_xon: 1
     rx_flow_control_xoff: 1
     tx_flow_control_xon: 0
     tx_flow_control_xoff: 0
     rx_csum_offload_good: 3531089
     rx_csum_offload_errors: 0
     rx_header_split: 0
     alloc_rx_buff_failed: 0
     tx_smbus: 0
     rx_smbus: 0
     dropped_smbus: 0
     rx_dma_failed: 0
     tx_dma_failed: 0
     rx_hwtstamp_cleared: 0
     uncorr_ecc_errors: 0
     corr_ecc_errors: 0
     tx_hwtstamp_timeouts: 0
     tx_hwtstamp_skipped: 0
```

Netstat -s

Ip:
    Forwarding: 2
    2440251 total packets received
    29 with invalid addresses
    0 forwarded
    0 incoming packets discarded
    2438237 incoming packets delivered
    4842421 requests sent out
    20 outgoing packets dropped
    43 dropped because of missing route
Icmp:
    43 ICMP messages received
    0 input ICMP message failed
    ICMP input histogram:
        destination unreachable: 43
    43 ICMP messages sent
    0 ICMP messages failed
    ICMP output histogram:
        destination unreachable: 43
IcmpMsg:
        InType3: 43
        OutType3: 43
Tcp:
    143 active connection openings
    56 passive connection openings
    136 failed connection attempts
    9 connection resets received
    3 connections established
    2436528 segments received
    4846667 segments sent out
    0 segments retransmitted
    0 bad segments received
    148 resets sent
Udp:
    714 packets received
    43 packets to unknown port received
    0 packet receive errors
    760 packets sent
    0 receive buffer errors
    0 send buffer errors
    IgnoredMulti: 1077
UdpLite:
TcpExt:
    35 TCP sockets finished time wait in fast timer
    27 delayed acks sent
    43 delayed acks further delayed because of locked socket
    Quick ack mode was activated 39 times
    6055 packet headers predicted
    2416400 acknowledgments not containing data payload received
    5951 predicted acknowledgments
    Detected reordering 1 times using SACK
    TCPBacklogCoalesce: 2272
    TCPDSACKOldSent: 39
    1 connections reset due to early user close
    4 connections aborted due to timeout
    TCPSackShiftFallback: 1
    TCPRcvCoalesce: 53
    TCPAutoCorking: 2917463
    TCPOrigDataSent: 4845430
    TCPHystartTrainDetect: 28
    TCPHystartTrainCwnd: 594
    TCPWinProbe: 3
    TCPKeepAlive: 1
    TCPDelivered: 4845420
IpExt:
    InBcastPkts: 1077
    InOctets: 116085858
    OutOctets: 1318972240
    InBcastOctets: 357885
    InNoECTPkts: 2440254

Comment: Why do you think that "device interrupt" is incorrect and needs to be fixed? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395862/ifconfig-device-interrupt Possibly helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205141/what-exactly-is-an-ifconfig-dropped-rx-packet I doubt that 55 dropped is a significant issue. 5,500? Maybe.

Comment: the thing is it keeps raising really fast

Comment: RX packets 34137  bytes 24707415 (24.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1629  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17784  bytes 14339919 (14.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xb0a00000-b0a20000

I still get this afther 10min running the machine, (i restarted it) and it keeps going up

Comment: RX packets 3540027  bytes 251249030 (251.2 MB)
RX errors 0  dropped 4133  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 6994332  bytes 2043192764 (2.0 GB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
device interrupt 16  memory 0xb0a00000-b0a20000

Comment: Did you start at the link I gave? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205141/what-exactly-is-an-ifconfig-dropped-rx-packet I'd start by trying a different, ideally new cable.

Comment: i Found some drops using the DropWatch, but i still dont know how to fix them... Or cant i fix them?
8 drops at netlink_broadcast_filtered+257 (0xffffffff8639f0e7)
3 drops at __netif_receive_skb_core+14e (0xffffffff8633411e)
2 drops at __udp4_lib_rcv+ae5 (0xffffffff863e9da5)

Comment: i did start at your link but i cant see why that is related to my computer/nuc, i am using wired ethernet cable also tried diffrent ones, all the same rx drops, also tried connecting it straight to the modem

Comment: I wonder if the packet drops reported by the kernel are benign (dropping multicasts not meant for the device for example). Is the behavior the same or different on other devices on the network? Is the behavior changed at all if *all* other devices on the network are powered down?

Comment: if i try to see rx drops on my main windows computer it also seems to say it has rx drops... but what can it cause?

Comment: What does `netstat -s` tell us?

Comment: a lot i posted it above in the question

Comment: also for a weird reason all drops are gone by doing tcpdump